# Reading bytes from Arduino using Python

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to read serial input from Arduino in Python. I am trying to do a simple task - my Arduino has one button writing to serial its state. This is the code for the Arduino:

```
const int ledPin = 7;
const int buttonPin = 2;
int buttonState= 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}
void loop() {
 buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
 if(buttonState == LOW){ digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);} else digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  Serial.println(buttonState); 
  delay(50);
}
```

Using serial monitor in Arduino 1.8.13 software I can see it prints either 0 or 1.

I'm trying to read it with the following code in Python:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM10', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)
 
t = 0
while t<10:
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode()
    print(arduinoData)
    t+=1
print(type(arduinoData))
ser.close()
```

I read the first 10 inputs and print the type of the `arduinoData`which in this case is string, since I'm using `.decode()`. However, I can't use boolean operators such as `arduinoData=='1'` to do anything, even though it is decoded to string. I have tried using `.decode('ascii')`, `.decode('UTF-8')` to no avail.

How can I check the values or how can I scrap the `.decode()` and convert the bytes to simple integers to then use boolean operators?
I am using python 3.9 with an Arduino Uno.

UPDATE 1

I've managed to convert it from `str` to `int` this way in Python:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM10', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)

t=0
while t<10:
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode()
    print(arduinoData)
    t+=1
if(int(arduinoData) == 1):
    print("Input is 1")
ser.close()
```

This way I can see that indeed my serial input is equal to 1. However I wish to do something if it is not equal to 1. So I put the checking in the loop like so:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM10', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)

t=0
while t<10:
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode()
    print(arduinoData)
    if(int(arduinoData) == 1):
        print("Input is 1")
    t+=1

ser.close()
```

And get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\01132892\Desktop\Serial\SerialButtonPurple.py", line 12, in <module>
    if(int(arduinoData) == 1):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I am assuming this is a problem with converting it inside the loop, however I have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

My Python isn't all that good, but maybe `ser.readline()` also returns the EOL? If so, `arduinoData` doesn't contain just the "1".

If I'm right, *it should work if you strip off the EOL*.

Alternatively: have the Arduino send single bytes with `Serial.print(buttonState);` and read single bytes in Python with `ser.read()`. There is no need for a delimiter when you send and read single bytes.

Comment: Hi!
Certainly you are right - because without `decode()` Python reads something like `b'1\n\r'`.
However if I were to use `Serial.print(buttonState)` I wouldn't really have a delimeter to mark individual readings I think

Comment: You don't need a delimiter if you both send and read single bytes, and ser.read() reads single bytes.

Don't forget to vote and/or accept the answer, so the question doesn't remain open. Only accept if I make sense, of course 8-).

Comment: I will send different parameters at the same time (multiple buttons) so it will be easier

Comment: Your edited answer is similar to my updated way, sadly it also has the same error (I attached it to the original question)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've managed to solve the problem.
Please note that to check whether it is working in the main loop, I am pressing key 'a' if the button is not pressed (signal read is 0) and releasing it if the signal is 1.

```
import serial
import pynput

ser = serial.Serial('COM10', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
while 1:
    arduinoData = ser.readline().rstrip()
    print(arduinoData)
    if(arduinoData==b'0'):
        keyboard.press('a')
    else:
        keyboard.release('a')
ser.close()
```

I would like to thank **ocrdu** for suggesting to use the `rstrip()` to get rid of EOL.